# How should I get the column number from a ListView?

Tags: android, listview

My ListView contains a number of blocks, arranged in such a way as to look like columns.

At the moment, I can find the row number, but I'm struggling to get the column.

What I think I'm looking for is for a way to discover either

- The view the user tapped on
- The horizontal coordinate of the tap and work it out from that.
- Some other way I haven't thought of.

Real question: How should I get the column number from a ListView?

Comment: Can you post your code. And which view you are using is it a ListView or a GridView ?

Comment: If you don't post any code it's impossible for anyone to give you a definite answer.

Comment: @Triode I'm using ListView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing the `onClick(View view)` method of the tapped view from the adapter class which you have bind to listview.

Here is an example:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ContactHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ContactHolder();
        holder.imgPhone = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgPhone);
        holder.imgPhone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);


                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contactArrayList.get(position).phone_number));
                context.startActivity(callIntent);
            }
        });


        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ContactHolder) row.getTag();

    return row;
}
```

Comment: Aside from being the only answer, this is the best answer because it shows the use of tag. The tag can hold an object of cell and table attributes. Thank BugraOral